# Application arraylist clears

Tags: android, share, garbage

I have an application which has several screens. Lets say A B C D and D might open some external application as well.

All this activities share data, an arraylist with one another and I have created a reference to it in my Application class. (I have created a class which extends Application and referred to it manifest.) So all these are using single instance of arraylist. A initializes the arraylist since its first screen and others might modify it.

The problem is when I test this on emulator nothing gets broken. But on 'some' phones after 3+ screens of navigation arraylist just clears from the heap. No matter how small size is.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `singleton` class for your ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Use singleton design pattern or make your object static

With the Singleton design pattern you can:

- Ensure that only one instance of a class is created
- Provide a global point of access to the object
- Allow multiple instances in the future without affecting a singleton class's clients

Comment: There are 4 activities as I said and an Application class, I cannot share the code because there are thousands of lines

Answer (score -1):

Declare `ArrayList` as `static` in your first `Activity` then use it from any it will not broke up.

Comment: why down voting can anybody explains?

Comment: Well, static is not meant for these scenarios right ? I didn't vote you down , but it might be the reason.

Comment: @Shardul Thanks, I know that when we use static but then also I think its good approach in terms of android programming